# Ruby - How do I make a perfect counter method

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby program here that counts the number of the computer won and the user won. The idea here is whoever got 5 wins FIRST will be the winner and will output a special message "You won 5 times you are really the winner!" :

```
VALID_CHOICES = { 
 'l' => 'light',
 'p' => 'prost', 
 'k' => 'kronge',
}

def display(message)
  Kernel.puts("=>#{message}")
end

def test_win?(first, second)
  (first == 'l' && second == 'p') ||
    (first == 'p' && second == 'k') ||
    (first == 'k' && second == 'p') ||
end

player_count = 0
computer_count = 0
end
```

Counter please.

How can I make sure I'll got the proper logic on this as I count the wins of both side?

Comment: you didn't call output_results

Comment: It's actually there.

Comment: Could you add a clarification what the problem is, like "When I run this program with x, then I expect the output y, but I always get 'blah'"

Comment: the problem here is that my counter doesnt work need to fix it

Comment: What do you mean "you **believe** you have an issue"? Do you have an issue or not? Or do you think you are only hallucinating the issue? What *is* that mysterious issue you believe you may or may not have? What is the behavior you are expecting? Do you observe that expected behavior? If not, what is the behavior you are getting? If yes, why do you believe you have an issue? Do you get an error message? If yes, what is it? Where you do you get it? When do you get it? Under which circumstances do you get it? What is the precise text of the error message? Please, provide a [mcve] that precisely …

Comment: … demonstrates your problem. The vast majority of problems should usually be able to be demonstrated in about 5 lines of code or so.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is *not* a precise enough description to be able to say anything even remotely useful about your problem.

Comment: @JohnCarter I guess what Herr Mittag says is pretty much what I meant ^^ I think I already know what your problem is, but it would be nice to have the question updated with expected vs actual results, so other users can follow the thread :)

Comment: Try this format for your question: `this is my codebase` when I do `some codeblock` I would expect to see X, but instead I get error/other result

Comment: Hi guys. There is no problem here. I AM ONLY ASKING IF YOU HAVE ANY IDEA ON HOW TO MAKE A PERFECT COUNTER THAT WILL COUNT THE WINS OF BOTH THE COMPUTER AND PLAYER BASED ON MY CODES NOW. Thanks.,

Comment: http://theoatmeal.com/pl/minor_differences/capslock

Comment: Sorry about that, Capslock.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be rude, but I do not understand how your code is supposed to work. Is that your complete script and you run it with ruby x.rb, or is this a snippet that runs in a loop or...?

Comment: I am still confused about this question. You say the problem is that it doesn't work and you need to fix it. But you also say there is no problem here. So, which is it? Does it work or doesn't it work? Is there a problem with the code or is there no problem with the code? If it doesn't work, *how* doesn't it work? Does it give the wrong results? If yes, which ones? And what would be the correct results? Why? Does it give no results? Does it give an error? What is the precise text of the error and the location it points to? What do you mean by "counter method"? What is its behavior? What do …

Comment: … mean by "perfect"? What objective criteria do you use to measure perfectness? Can you provide a set of example inputs and outputs? Can you provide an abstract description of the desired behavior? Can you provide test cases?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
def output_results(player, computer)

      if win?(player, computer)
        player_count+= 1
        if player_count == 5
         display("You won!")
        end
      elsif win?(computer, player)
        computer_count+= 1
        if computer_count == 5
          display("Computer won! You loose!")
        end
      else
        display("It's a tie! No one wins!")
      end

    end
```

Comment: It's actually the same thing. Do you know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I do not really understand what the problem is, but based on the code you posted, here is a working example - by no means is it "perfect", it is merely a starting point.

```
VALID_CHOICES = {
 'l' => 'light',
 'p' => 'prost',
 'k' => 'kronge',
}

@player_count = 0
@computer_count = 0
@end_game = false

def display(message)
  Kernel.puts("=>#{message}")
end

def test_win?(first, second)
  (first == 'l' && second == 'p') ||
    (first == 'p' && second == 'k') ||
    (first == 'k' && second == 'p')
end

def output_results(player, computer)
  if test_win?(player, computer)
    @player_count += 1
    if @player_count == 5
      @end_game = true
      display("You won the game!")
    else
      display("You won this round!")
    end
  elsif test_win?(computer, player)
    @computer_count += 1
    if @computer_count == 5
      @end_game = true
      display("Computer won! You loose!")
    else
      display("Computer won this round!")
    end
  else
    display("It's a tie! No one wins!")
  end

  display("Player: #{@player_count}")
  display("Computer: #{@computer_count}")
end

until @end_game
  computer_choice = VALID_CHOICES.keys.sample
  display("==================================================================")
  display("Choose your weapon (type l for Light, p for Prost, k for Kronge): ")
  choice = Kernel.gets().chomp()
  display("==================================================================")


  display("You chose: #{VALID_CHOICES[choice]}, computer choose: #{VALID_CHOICES[computer_choice]}")
  output_results(choice, computer_choice)
end
```

Assuming you save this file as "my_game.rb" you can run it with `ruby my_game.rb` in your command prompt (you have to be in the correct folder).

EDIT: We can open a chat if this doesnt help you or you have more questions.